# How to let SonarQube to check NullPointerException when calling library method

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to find the proper way to identify the dangerous usage of nullable library methods with SonarQube.

The example below illustrates the potential NullPointerException that may be raised by calling `asText()` method on the nullable JsonNode object returned from the `node.get("something")` call.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Tst {
    public String getSomething(String json) throws Exception {
        JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
        
        return node.get("something").asText();
    }
}
```

I expect to have the line `return node.get("something").asText();` to be marked as the bug, but the problem is not identified by our SonarQube 9.8 Server.

How to let SonarQube understand that ***com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.get()*** method is nullable?